# update_post_meta() with a modified array?

Tags: array, save-post, post-meta

When in wp-admin I want to manipulate one value of an array and then update the post_meta with this array. My array looks like this:

```
1285
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["description"]=>
    string(26) "description text goes here"
    ["food"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
}
```

Here 'description' and 'food' are custom fields. What I want to do is manipulate the value of 'description'. Instead of using the value of the custom field 'description', I would like to replace it with the post_content (`the_content();`). The rest of the fields (in this case just 'food') I want to update with the actual value of the custom field.

Now, I know that the code below should update the post_meta with the actual custom field values, but how can i manipulate one of them as mentioned above?

```
function cf_description_to_content($post_ID){
$array = $_POST['wiloke_listgo_my_custom_fields'];
update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'wiloke_listgo_my_custom_fields', $array ); 
}
add_action('save_post', 'cf_description_to_content', 100, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:
 
`function cf_description_to_content($post_ID){
    $data = get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'wiloke_listgo_my_custom_fields', true );
    // Put whatver description you want assign to the description field
    $data['description'] = $_POST['wiloke_listgo_my_custom_fields'];
    update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'wiloke_listgo_my_custom_fields', $data ); 
}
add_action('save_post', 'cf_description_to_content', 100, 1);`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Please tell me; why use `,true` in `get_post_meta`?

Comment: For more information, visit WordPress official site: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: The `get_post_meta` function receive the the third parameter as (boolean) (optional) If set to true then the function will return a single result, as a string.

If `false`, or not set, then the function returns an array of the custom fields. This may not be intuitive in the context of serialized arrays. If you fetch a serialized array with this method you want `$single` to be true to actually get an unserialized array back. If you pass in `false`, or leave it out, you will have an array of one, and the value at index `0` will be the serialized string. Default: `false`